# Saving multiple field values in a users entity

Tags: 8, nodes

I am trying to reference other nodes on the user entity on field_clinic but everything else is saving except that multiple value field. What could i be doing wrong. The field_clinic accepts multiple values. Below is my code:

```
$clinics = [

        array('value' => 132),
        array('value' => 133),
        array('value' => 134),
    ];



    // if the user exsists update basestation
    $UserEntity = User::create([
        'name' => 'Final',
        'roles' => array('subscriber'),
        'field_age' => '2',
        'field_city' => 12,
        'field_clinic' => $clinics,
        'field_base_statition' =>  $bs_nid


    ]);

    $UserEntity->save();
```

The clinics array contains the node ids that I am trying to reference. Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you're setting the values may be failing to work if you've got the wrong keys in your array - setting any field from code requires you to know how that specific field type stores its data in the entity.

If you're not sure about that key, using the [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module you can simply save one of those users filling the `field_clinic` field with appropriate values then switch to the `devel` tab for that user and inspect what keys are actually being used to store the values in that field (probably one named `target_id`).

According to what you find there, fixing your code may be just matter of changing this:

```
$clinics = [
    array('value' => 132),
    array('value' => 133),
    array('value' => 134),
];
```

to this:

```
$clinics = [
    ['target_id' => 132],
    ['target_id' => 133],
    ['target_id' => 134],
];
```

(disregard the difference between declaring an array using the `[]` or the `array()`, I used the former in my edited code just for coherency)